# Retrieving value from HTML table

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

Currently all this does is retrieve data from specific columns, the final result will be that I will check the data to make sure that it passes the test cases, but I want to look at this foreach right now and see if I can't make it a little simpler.

A lot of what I have coded I have come back and turned into Linq statements and made things a lot simpler (shorter), and I would really like to do the same with this foreach statement, but not real sure how to do it.

I hate to admit that I am very new to using Linq, I can read it for the most part but still have a little difficulty when writing more complex statements/queries.

Is there something that I can do to make this a lot more simple before I code any more on this *Scenario*, I would like to simplify so that I don't write extraneous code that will be refactored out when I make this more clear.

I have also been trying to find something that imports the HTML table into a nice neat object that I can query, but everything I have found so far has been similar to what I am doing or more complex than what I am doing here.

```
[Then(@"see the '(.*)' of '(.*)'")]
public void ThenSeeThe(string columnHeader, string entryName)
{
    var htmlTable = Ie.FindElementByClassName("table");
    var tableHeaders = htmlTable.FindElements(By.TagName("th"));
    var rows = new List<List<string>>();

    var htmlRows = htmlTable.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));

    foreach (var htmlRow in htmlRows)
    {
        //first row holds the table headers
        if (htmlRow.FindElements(By.TagName("th")).Count > 0)
        {
            var thList = tableHeaders.Select(th => th.Text.ToString()).ToList();
            rows.Add(thList);
            continue;
        }

        var cellsInRow = htmlRow.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
        var cells = cellsInRow.Select(cell => cell.Text.ToString()).ToList();
        rows.Add(cells);
    }

    var columnIndex = rows.First().IndexOf(columnHeader);
    var field = rows.Where(x => x[0] == entryName).Select(x => x[columnIndex]).First();
    if (columnHeader == "Create UTC Date")
    {
        _CreateUTC = Convert.ToDateTime(field);
    }
    else if (columnHeader == "Modify UTC Date")
    {
        _ModifyUTC = Convert.ToDateTime(field);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the role of this procedure (which is far from obvious from the name alone) is to assign either `_CreateUTC` or `_ModifyUTC` values (which should be `_createUTC` and `_modifyUTC` if they're private fields - always use `camelCase` for fields and locals/parameters.

You don't need that `rows` list of lists of strings at all, let alone iterate that monster afterward to retrieve a value.

Just loop and locate the value as you're looping, don't store anything but what you need and stop looping once you got it - I think something like this would do it:

```
var headerIndex = 0;
DateTime value;
foreach (var htmlRow in htmlRows)
{
    if (htmlRow.FindElements(By.TagName("th")).Count > 0)
    {
        headerIndex = tableHeaders.Select(th => th.Text.ToString()).IndexOf(columnHeader);
        continue;
    }

    var cellsInRow = htmlRow.FindElements(By.TagName("td")).ToArray();
    if (cellsInRow[0] == entryName)
    {
        value = Convert.ToDateTime(cellsInRow[headerIndex].Text.ToString());
        break;
    }
}

if (columnHeader = "Create UTC Date")
{
    _createUTC = value;
}
else if (columnHeader = "Modify UTC Date")
{
    _modifyUTC = value;
}
```

Comment: This is a very good response to the code given, unfortunately because of what I am coding I actually need to create a way to compare the state of the table before and after certain actions/changes.  If I were just pulling in this data once, I would do it this way, and I may still do this depending on how the rest of this feature goes, and how I track the row location.  thank you for the review

Comment: I don't understand. 99% of the data you're collecting is useless and not kept anywhere, it's all local. Or did you not list your *actual, real code*?

Comment: it is actual, real code, but as I have been coding I have been adding new code and changing code to better fit my requirements and to make the code clearer and less redundant for what I am doing with the scenarios. so, I eventually want to be able to check all the columns,  I am not sure whether I want to hold all the rows though, so I think I might be able to get away with only extracting the table header and the actual row that matches the item I want to inspect.